# Получение количества родителей в xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath

Есть Xml

```
<tasks>
    <task id="1">
        <task id="2" />
    </task>
    <task id="4">
        <task id="8" />
    </task>
    <task id="5">
        <task id="7">
            <task id="9" />
        </task>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

Каким образом получить количество родителей у каждого элемента task?

чтобы у элемента с
**id=9** кол-во родителей показывалось равное ***2***,

у **id=7** кол-во родителей ***1***,

у **id=5** соответственно кол-во родителей ***0***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Функция XPath `count` умеет считать количество узлов в наборе.
2. Ось XPath `ancestor::` обращается ко всем предкам данного узла.
3. Ограничиваем ось только элементами с именем task `ancestor::task`

Итого Вам нужно `<xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::task)" />`

Полный код решения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- для отладки я выводил в текстовый файл -->
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <!-- Выбираем корневой элемент -->
    <xsl:template match="tasks">
        <!-- Выбираем все дочерние элементы с заданным именем -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//task"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Для каждого элемента с именем task -->
    <xsl:template match="task">
        <!-- выводим атрибут id -->
        <xsl:text>id=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />

        <!-- выводим количество ( предков :: с заданным именем )-->
        <xsl:text>; parents=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::task)" />

        <!-- перевод строки для текстового файла -->
        <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Пишет текст

```
id=1; parents=0
id=2; parents=1
id=4; parents=0
id=8; parents=1
id=5; parents=0
id=7; parents=1
id=9; parents=2
```